# Condition on matrix to ensure nontrivial Jordan canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra

In my understanding, in order to ensure that a matrix $A$ has a nontrivial Jordan canonical form, one needs to come up with such a matrix whose geometric multiplicity is less than algebraic multiplicity for at least one eigenvalue $\lambda$.

But what conditions does $A$ need to have in order for us to quickly see that it has a nontrivial Jordan form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

The algebraic and geometric multiplicities of $\lambda$ are different iff 
there is a vector $v$ such that $(A - \lambda I) v \ne 0 $ but $(A - \lambda I)^2 v = 0$.

You could write this condition (in the case $\lambda \ne 0$) as:

there is a vector $v$ such that $ A^2 v = 2 \lambda A v - \lambda^2 v \ne \lambda^2 v $.

EDIT: 
A necessary condition is that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of the characteristic polynomial is $0$.  If so, the $\lambda$'s to consider are the roots of the greatest common divisor (in the sense of polynomials) of the characteristic polynomial and its derivative.  So you don't need **all** the eigenvalues, but to get a positive answer you do need to find some of them.

Comment: Is there something that we can immediately see from the matrix, without the need to find its eigenvalues first? For otherwise we would need to use the method of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You've sort of answered your own question.

Suppose $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with algebraic multiplicity $m_a$. If
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}
\dim\null(A-\lambda I)\neq m_a
$$
then $A$ is not diagonalizable.

So, to check if $A$ is not diagonalizable, we need only find such an eigenvalue.

Comment: So we need to ensure this about the multiplicity, which I'd also thought about. But is there something that we can immediately see from the matrix, without the need to find its eigenvalues first? For otherwise we would need to use the method of trial and error.